# ActionResult is not hitting when using [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view, controller

When I used `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` for my Action Result , it show the error

HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

When I remove `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]`, it works fine.
Why it happened?  the piece of code is

```
[AcceptVerbs( HttpVerbs.Post )]//will do action when we use Html.BeginForm()
public ActionResult GenerateReport( FormCollection fromCollection )//FormCollection:It provides to access  the values that were just posted to your page. 
{
    ReportInfo reportInfo = new ReportInfo();
    reportInfo.PatientId = "1111";
    reportInfo.PatientName = fromCollection.Get("patientName");
    reportInfo.PatientSex = "female";
    reportInfo.Findings=fromCollection.Get("Findings");
    reportInfo.History = fromCollection.Get("History"); 
    FillImageUrl( reportInfo, "PatientData.png" );
    return this.ViewPdf( "Radiology Report", "Index", reportInfo );

}
```

Can you please suggest a solution to resolve this error

Comment: Try [HttpPost] instead of that syntax

Comment: May be Form is looking for Get method generally for the Get method attribute is not defined. So when you remove the [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] attribute it worked.

Comment: Could you show us your view/form.
I think you specified something badly in your form.